# Custom validation not working Cakephp 2.6.6 + Cake DC search plugin

Tags: cakephp-2.6

Good morning

I use cakephp 2.6.6 and plugin cakedc search.

I have a strange problem. It does not work to me self-validation. Validation built-in cakephp works. My unfortunately not working.

Please help and thank you

Code:

```
public function abab($check) {


        die('test');

}


public $validate = array(
        'company_name' => array(
            'role' => 'notEmpty' // It's ok
        ),
        'surname' => array(
            'role' => 'notEmpty' // It's ok
        ), 
        'telephone' => array(
            'role' => 'notEmpty' // etc
        ),
        'nip_number' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'role' => 'notEmpty' // etc
            ),
            'cust' => array(
                'role' => 'abab' // no ok
            )

        )
    )
```

Comment: I would add: I appeal to abab() method on other models. I can not refer only to the model associated with the cake dc search

Comment: Perhaps you mean `'rule'` instead of `'role'`?